# Change value textbox from another form and form position is Showing C#

Tags: c#, forms

I want to change the value of textbox1 in form2 from another form (form1). If the position of the form2 is closed the code can be executed (there is no problem), but if the position of the form2 has been opened then the value textbox does not change when the button on form1 is clicked.

**Form2**

```
public string Fullname
{
  get
    {
      return textbox1.Text;
    }
  set
    {
      textbox1.Text = value;
    }
}
```

**Form1**

```
Form2 frm = new Form2();
frm.Fullname = textBox1.Text;
frm.Show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        Form2 frm = new Form2();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm.Show();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm.textBox1.Text = "Changed";
    }
```

this Code worked just fine for me .  or you can implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your property's class 
it should detect the changes

Comment: isn't `textBox` a private member of the form, you haven't access to from another form?

Comment: _you will need to make it public_ - that not a good advise ;)